# How do I call a WMI method with an object reference parameter from WMIC?

Tags: object, batch-file, reference, parameter-passing, wmic

How do I call a WMI method (e.g. [`RemoveVirtualSystemSnapshot()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) where the first parameter is a reference to the `CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData`) with an object reference parameter **from WMIC**?

I haven't found how to refer to an object. I can find the object with WMIC, but I don't know how to get from `wmic path ... where ...` that returns some text output to a WMIC command that calls `RemoveVirtualSystemSnapshot()` with that object as the first parameter.

I'm sure I can do this many other ways (C#, VBScript, ...), but I'm wondering if it is possible with WMIC?

Comment: have you found out if this can be done. I need this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact not possible according to the documentation from Microsoft. Microsoft states the following information:

**Problem:** Input parameter is of OBJECT type

**Cause:** Support is not fully implemented yet for input parameters which are of the OBJECT type. The default value (an empty string: "") is the only value currently supported.

**Solution:** Use the following command to set sharing of the c:\test directory for three users:
WMIC SHARE CALL Create "","test","3","TestShareName","","c:\test",0

You can find this information on their "Troubleshooting WMIC" page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738752(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_8

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible.However here's how `WMIC` represents the objects:

`\\HostName\ROOT\cimv2:ClassName.Key1="Key1Value",Key2="Key2Value",..`

(can be seen ASSOC verb ) but I don't it's possible to be used with WMIC -I've tried a lot of things - but still the object representations are taken as strings.Another thing is MOFCOMP where you can compile .mof file and create an object with alias , but it still can be passed to a method.My last hope is to use some of the odbc/sql command line tools that come packed with the Windows and use more complex WQL queries , but probably it's pointless...

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find any way either. If you happen to find it, please update the answer. Until then, marking this as accepted answer.

Comment: have you found out if one can use the reference to get the object in WMI?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160815124446/https://www.exploit-monday.com/2016/08/wmi-persistence-using-wmic.html), you can get a string value referencing an object with the following command:

```
wmic PATH <ClassName> GET __RELPATH /FORMAT:LIST
```

and then pass it to the parameter/​property accepting that type of object.